# not save data to 2 table have foreigenkey oncakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, associations, cakephp-2.x

On project cakephp. I have 2 model

```
<?php class VisaPerson extends AppModel {
public $name = 'VisaPerson';
public $primaryKey  = 'id';}?>
```

and

```
<?php class VisaProcess extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'VisaProcess';
    public $primaryKey  = 'id';
    public $belongsTo = array(
            'VisaPerson' => array (
                    'className' => 'VisaPerson',
                    'foreignKey' => 'people_id'
            )
    );
}
?>
```

In controller, I writed:

```
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
           $person = $this->VisaPerson->save($this->request->data);
           if (!empty($person)) {
               $this->request->data['VisaProcess']['people_id'] = $this->$person->id;
               $this->VisaPerson->VisaProcess->save($this->request->data);
        }
    }
```

Data saved on VisaPerson but on VisaProcess people_id not auto save.
Plese help me!

Comment: Please read up on saving associations, what you're doing there is unnecessary and error prone, CakePHP can handle saving associations out of the box: **https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html**

Answer (score 0):

As I remember you need to add this into yours VisaPerson model:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'VisaProcess' => array(
        'className'  => 'VisaProcess',
        'foreignKey' => 'people_id'
    )
);
```

After that you only need to save VisaPerson and both tables will be filled (if `$this->request->data['VisaProcess']` and `$this->request->data['VisaPerson']` exists):

```
$this->VisaPerson->save($this->request->data);
```

Comment: @Hongnguyen try `$this->VisaPerson->saveAll($this->request->data);` %-) And what cake version are you using?

Comment: I using cake version 2